# How to get the innerHTML of all first child elements as a list or dataframe

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I would like to get the `innerHTML` of all first child elements of a specific tag that the class name is "list-group" by using selenium or `beautifulsoup` in python.

HTML code:

```
<div id="history_1" class="list-group">
        <div>
                <p>a</p>
        </div>
        <div>
                <p>b</p>
        </div>
        <div>
                <p>c</p>
        </div>
        <p>
                d
        </p>
</div>
<div>
....
</div>
<div id="history_2" class="list-group">
        <div>
                <p>e</p>
        </div>
        <div>
                <p>f</p>
        </div>
        <div>
                <p>g</p>
        </div>
        <p>
                h
        </p>
</div>
```

I want to get the result like below:

result[0] = "`<div><p>a</p></div>`"

result[1] = "`<div><p>b</p></div>`"

result[2] = "`<div><p>c</p></div>`"

result[3] = "`<p>d</p>`"

result[4] = "`<div><p>e</p></div>`"

result[5] = "`<div><p>f</p></div>`"

result[6] = "`<div><p>g</p></div>`"

result[7] = "`<p>h</p>`"

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refers to what you want to achieve, you want to get `outerHTML`, not `innerHTML`.

Use `//*` to query all nodes and `parent` to meet your needs, like this:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[parent::*[@class='list-group']]")
for element in elements:
    print(element.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the below line.

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='list-group']/*")
```